# Strongly type HttpClient across sub application

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I'm trying to create a main app with an authentication process on a WebApi and then the app give access to a bunch of "sub app" using the same WebApi.

For that I have register my HttpClient with this :

```cs
private void ConfigureServices(IConfiguration configuration, IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpClient<BimFluxService>(); 
    services.AddSingleton<MainWindow>();
    services.AddSingleton<MainViewModel>();
}
```

Each sub app is a different Solution and for each one of them I need to access my `BimFluxService` which is initiated like this :

```cs
public BimFluxService(HttpClient client, ILogger<BimFluxService> logger)
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5001");
    Client = client;
    Logger = logger;
}

private HttpClient Client { get; }
internal static ILogger<BimFluxService> Logger { get; private set; }
public IUser User { get; private set; }
```

on the main app my Client is correctly working. The `IUser` property is updating when authenticated.
But on the sub app the `BimFluxService` looks like a new instance and `IUser` isn't updated.

I'm using this to register my addin into the host :

```cs
.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
{
    ConfigureServices(context.Configuration, services);
    foreach (var initAddin in addins)
    {
        services = initAddin.RegisterApp(services);
    }
})
```

did I missed something ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround but I'm not sure how good is it.

I create my services with this :

```cs
services.AddHttpClient();
services.AddSingleton<BimFluxService>();
```

and with that my HttpClientType is the same everywhere.